# How Response object will be created?

Tags: asp.net

When we are about to write some code in the .aspx.cs file , we are able to access Response object.

How we are getting that object, and where it is presented, and how its working as a object as  we haven't created that

Is it a property?

Is it a class?

Tell me all variations about Response object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a class, present inside `System.Web` namespace. For more answers, please read the following link it had all the details for the `Response` object you're taking about.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Explain in your words , i am getting confused when i am reading

Comment: Teach me in all variations